# Calling methods from header using macros

Tags: c++, templates, macros, header

I have written a basic reflection library in c++ and am able to to register my classes/fields like so:

```
addType<Color>()
    ->addField(Field::createField("r", &Color::r))
    ->addField(Field::createField("g", &Color::g))
    ->addField(Field::createField("b", &Color::b))
    ->addField(Field::createField("a", &Color::a));
```

However I now want to register all my classes inside of there own header files (ideally using macros) like this:

```
REGISTER_TYPE(Color);
REGISTER_FIELD(r, &Color::r);
```

Or at least in a way similar, however to do this i need to call methods inside the headers (at startup), is this possible / what is the standard/best way to do this purely inside the headers? and will it increase the size of the final generated executable/dynamic library?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does your header be included in several translation units ?

Comment: All my reflectable class/struct headers are used in many places (and are included into many translation units).

Comment: Generally, there is a macro in header for 'declaration', and one in cpp for 'implement' (using static variable initialisation to call function).